# ubuntu: upgrading

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, apt-get

i have some kind of problem with my system (it's a kvm vm with 2 gig ram and 50gig hd). when i try to install "linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae" using apt-get, i'm told that there's no space left on the device:

```
root@social:~/backup# apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/38.2 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae (3.2.0-38.60) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
The link /initrd.img is a dangling linkto /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 3.2.0-38-generic-pae /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
cp: writing `/tmp/mkinitramfs_lUydlU/lib/modules/3.2.0-38-generic-pae/modules.order': **No space left on device**
cp: failed to extend `/tmp/mkinitramfs_lUydlU/lib/modules/3.2.0-38-generic-pae/modules.order': **No space left on device**
cp: writing `/tmp/mkinitramfs_lUydlU//lib/modules/3.2.0-38-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/hid/hid.ko': **No space left on device**
cp: failed to extend `/tmp/mkinitramfs_lUydlU//lib/modules/3.2.0-38-generic-pae/kernel/drivers/hid/hid.ko': **No space left on device**
```

this goes on for a few hundred (?) lines and the whole thing comes to an end with

```
cp: writing `/tmp/mkinitramfs_lUydlU//bin/date': No space left on device
cp: failed to extend `/tmp/mkinitramfs_lUydlU//bin/date': No space left on device
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fixrtc failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-38-generic-pae with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
Failed to process /etc/kernel/postinst.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae.postinst line 1010.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: dependency problems prevent     configuration of linux-image-generic-pae:
 linux-image-generic-pae depends on linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae; however:
  Package linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-image-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  dpkg: dependency problems     prevent configuration of linux-generic-pae:
 linux-generic-pae depends on linux-image-generic-pae (= 3.2.0.38.46); however:
  Package linux-image-generic-pae is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing linux-generic-pae (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae
 linux-image-generic-pae
 linux-generic-pae
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

now - disk space should'nt be a problem:

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda2        43G   12G   29G  30% /
udev            1.5G   12K  1.5G   1% /dev
tmpfs           606M  264K  605M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            1.5G     0  1.5G   0% /run/shm
/dev/vda1       894M   34M  812M   4% /boot
overflow        1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /tmp

#cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/vda2 during installation
UUID=6914ebff-843a-4f33-bc5f-ca8bb4be17c5 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/vda1 during installation
UUID=829b2017-2e30-4994-8689-1c79cca1e5c8 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/vda3 during installation
UUID=678da9f1-fda7-4849-890b-fadfeacad083 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

so - /tmp is mounted on a partition with 29 gig free disk space, there are 2 gig ram, of which according to "top" most is unused, there's a 4 gig swap partition... i don't see the problem :(

how to get this thing running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a very similar description of your problem here:

https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/34535

It looks like rebooting might be the trick. However, you should make very certain that your root-level kernel symlinks and contents of /boot are in shape before you do that, otherwise you might not be able to boot up.